# Fake a click to next slide in slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have a simple slick carousel (https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/), however in my layout it doesn't display correctly until you go through the first set of slides.

To get around this I just set it to autoplay but I don't actually want that to happen.

Is there a way to fake one of the arrows being clicked?

### Edit

```js
$('.carousel').slick({
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 4,
      slidesToScroll: 4,
      responsive: [
        {
          breakpoint: 1024,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 3,
            slidesToScroll: 3,
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 600,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 2,
            slidesToScroll: 2
          }
        },
        {
          breakpoint: 380,
          settings: {
            slidesToShow: 1,
            slidesToScroll: 1
          }
        }
      ]
    });
```

```css
a{
display:inline-block;
width:200px !important;
height:200px !important;
border: 1px solid DarkGrey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/kenwheeler/slick@1.8.1/slick/slick-theme.css"/>

<div class="card product">
  <div class="card-header" id="related_heading">
    <button class="btn btn-default collapsed w-100 h-100 text-left" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#related_body" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="related_body">
      <h5><span>+</span> RELATED PRODUCTS</h5>
    </button>
  </div>
  <div id="related_body" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="related_heading">
    <div class="product card-body">
      <div class="related-carousel">
        <div class="carousel">
          
          <a href="#">
          <img src="" alt="" itemprop="image">
          <p itemprop="name" class="product_name">product_name</p>
          <b>€116.85</b>
          </a>
          
          <a href="#">
          <img src="" alt="" itemprop="image">
          <p itemprop="name" class="product_name">product_name</p>
          <b>€116.85</b>
          </a>
          
          <a href="#">
          <img src="" alt="" itemprop="image">
          <p itemprop="name" class="product_name">product_name</p>
          <b>€116.85</b>
          </a>
          
          <a href="#">
          <img src="" alt="" itemprop="image">
          <p itemprop="name" class="product_name">product_name</p>
          <b>€116.85</b>
          </a>
          
          <a href="#">
          <img src="" alt="" itemprop="image">
          <p itemprop="name" class="product_name">product_name</p>
          <b>€116.85</b>
          </a>
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note how the links all line up under each other unless you try to drag across and then they go inline in the carousel.

Comment: See the `slickPrev` and `slickNext` [methods](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/#methods).

Comment: However, it seems that you're trying to work around a different issue ("layout it deosn't display correctly"). You might consider describing that original problem and providing a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to demonstrate.

Comment: You don't need to show everything, just the parts that are relevant to demonstrating the problem and a little more description about what's wrong with the layout. Incidentally, I can't find a "related products" section.

Comment: note the issue only happens on mobile

Comment: You can use the HTML output generated by PHP for an example, and include the relevant CSS and JS. The "related products" section at that link looks empty. Can you describe the problem?

Comment: @showdev hi thanks for continuing to help me with this, it was fairly awkward to try get an example that I could reproduce this with

Comment: Nicely done! I appreciate your efforts. Slick slider can't properly calculate element widths when the container is hidden. One solution is to initialize the slider only when the collapsed element is shown. Another solution is to manually reset the position of the initialized slider after it's shown. [Here's a demonstration](https://jsfiddle.net/1m2y6pLr/). For reference, see [Bootstrap collapse events](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/collapse/#events) and [Slick slider methods](https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick#methods)

Comment: @showdev thanks for your help got it sorted :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change slides programatically by using the methods `slickNext` and `slickPrev` on the slick instance.